# velocity in the relativistic momentum

Tags: special-relativity, momentum

I understand that, because of the change of a length (which is seen from a different frame of reference, moving at a constant speed relative to the first one) the volume of a body has to be different and that thus the mass of this body will be different in this second frame of reference (due to the density staying the same). But when transitioning from classical momentum to the relativistic momentum, the velocity which is (I think) also different in the other frame of reference, is not adapted and stays the same.
So why is there no change in velocity but only in the mass when going from $p = m×v$ to $p = γ×m×v$ ($γ$ being the Lorentz factor)?

Comment: Why do you think density doesn’t transform? Why do you think velocity doesn’t transform? Your second equation must have a typo because it is otherwise nonsense.

Comment: I thought so because otherwise I would not get that m' = m * k or at least I think it would be different. I that assumption right or have I made a mistake?

Comment: 1. Velocity-dependent “relativistic mass” is an obsolete concept that should never have existed. Today “mass” means velocity-independent “invariant mass”. 2. Please fix your second equation. You have $p$ on both sides. 3. Please write the Lorentz factor as $\gamma$, not $k$, if you want to be understood.

Comment: You seem to be conflating how quantities transform between inertial reference frames with how they “change” from Newtonian physics to relativistic physics. The difference between Newtonian to relativistic physics is not a change in reference frame!

Comment: So the density does change aswell and in the end it canceles out so that mass does not change from one frame of reference to the other?

Comment: If you transform from the rest frame of an object to a frame where it is moving, the mass stays the same, length contraction causes the volume to shrink, and therefore the density increases. But this has nothing to do with your two equations, neither of which is a transformation equation between two frames.

Comment: What does any of the stuff about mass have to do with your question?

Comment: @G.Smith oh. I think that this has been the root of my misconception. I thought of it as a transition between frames. Thank you very much for your help. This does answer my initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that, because of the change of a length (which is seen from a different frame of reference, moving at a constant speed relative to the first one) the volume of a body has to be different and that thus the mass of this body will be different in this second frame of reference (due to the density staying the same)

No, that's false. Only spatial and temporal dimensions change when you perform a Lorentz Transformation (LT for short). The mass $m$ is an intrinsic property of the object, so it is taken to be the same in any frame. Since volumes get contracted, the density *increases* when you perform a LT.

Okay, "so why the momentum definition changes in SR?" you may ask. Well, the classical definition $p=mu$ (I'm using $u$ to avoid confusion with the velocity in the transformation equations) is not conserved in collisions when you do a LT to change the reference frame, so it'd be useful to find a definition that rescues momentum conservation in SR. One may notice first that the classical definition doesn't transform nicely in LTs because, if in one frame we have
$$
p = m {dx \over dt}
$$
and, because of the LT,
$$
\begin{aligned}
dx' &= \gamma (dx - v \, dt)\\
dt' & = \gamma (dt - v \, dx /c^2),
\end{aligned}
$$
the momentum in the primed reference system, $p' = m dx'/dt'$, will have a complicated dependence on $p$, which is very different from the way $dx$ transforms to $dx'$ (which *is* relatively nice). $p$ transforms in the 'wrong' way because both the numerator and denominator of the velocity transforms, so if we could get only the numerator to transform then $p$ would transform just like $dx$. We do this by defining the *relativistic* momentum as 
$$
p = m {dx \over d\tau},
$$
where $d\tau$ is the proper time interval (the time measured in the frame where the object is *at rest* ), which is an *invariant* quantity in LTs. But, from the time dilation $dt = \gamma(u) \, d\tau$, we get
$$
p = \gamma(u) m {dx \over dt} = \gamma(u) m u,
$$
which *now* is conserved in any inertial frame *and* transforms in the same way as $dx$.